# Java TreeMaps with inheritance without instanceOf

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I am trying to write some Java classes to model a baseball team. A team has a roster of players that are either pitchers or position players. Each type of player has some unique methods, as shown in this UML diagram.

[image: UML for Project]

I'm trying to implement the `Team.calcPitchingStats()` method. This method needs to check the stats of every `Pitcher` on the roster.

Here is my current solution. I am not sure how good of practice this is or if it considered clean code but it is working. I am not 100% on the calculations but I have no idea what baseball is so. This is the whole function.

```
    public String calcPitchingStats(){
        int count = 0;
        int totInnings = 0;
        int totEarnedRuns = 0;
        double totEarnedRunAvg = 0.0;
        double totWhip = 0.0;

        for(Map.Entry<Integer, Player> player : roster.entrySet()){
            if(player.getValue().getClass() == Pitcher.class){
                
                Pitcher pitcher = (Pitcher) player.getValue();
                totInnings += pitcher.getInningsPitched();
                totEarnedRuns += pitcher.getEarnedRuns();
                totEarnedRunAvg += pitcher.getEarnedRunAverage();
                totWhip += pitcher.getWhip();
                count++;
            }
        }

        totEarnedRunAvg = totEarnedRunAvg / count;
        totWhip = totWhip / count;
        return "Total Innings: " + totInnings + " Total Earned Runs: " +
                totEarnedRuns + " Total Earned Run Average: " + totEarnedRunAvg
                + " Total Whip: " + totWhip;
    }
```

I am wondering if there is a way around using `instanceof` with a `TreeMap` to be able to access functions of the extended class. Possibly Java Generics?  I have been theorizing and possibly a template could work? The program knows they are either `Pitcher`s or `PositionPlayer`s though, because of the overridden call `toString()` methods. Just curious how to access these other methods with minimal processing and not using `instanceof`.

Comment: Specifically not `instanceof`? As in, could you use `player.getClass().isInstance(...)`?

Comment: Using instanceof is a code smell, which could indicate that your base class/interface is not optimal. You should override the provided methods in your base class and only use those in the higher level code e.g. getHits(), getStrikeOuts() etc.
P.S: I have no idea how the game (Baseball?) works excactly.

Comment: Im not really sure how baseball works either. My base class is abstract so I am not sure that override is possible. Also, I thought you would override in the Pitcher/Position Player class rather than the other way. Could I use an Interface?

Answer (score 0):

While your solution works, having explicit type checks or downcasting (casting from a supertype to a subtype) in object-oriented code often suggests that there's an issue with your design.

In this case, you may want to change how `Team` stores the list of players. Instead of (or in addition to) the roster of generic `Player` objects, you could add separate collections of `Pitcher`s and `PositionPlayer`s. That way, in the `calcPitchingStats()` method, you could just iterate over the collection of pitchers without any casting or type-checking.

If you can't alter the `Team` API and must deal with a collection of `Player` objects, then I would recommend using `instanceof` rather than `getClass()` as it's clearer and also correctly handles subclasses.